# USB stick with two partitions, one with a Debian image, won't boot

Tags: linux, boot, usb, partitioning, liveusb

I have a 16 GB USB stick that I split into two partitions using `gnome-disks`. The first one is an NTFS partition that I use like a normal USB stick for storage. On the second one, I installed the latest stable Debian ISO also using `gnome-disks`.

The first partition works as expected. But for some reason, I cannot boot into Debian using this stick. I even checked the option "bootable" in `gnome-disks` (for some reason it was not checked after writing the ISO). What is the problem?

I discovered that there is also a dedicated "live" ISO on the Debian website, which is about 1.5 GB smaller than the "standard" ISO. Do I really have to use the "live" one in order to be able to boot from the stick?

Also, is it common/okay to use the first partition as storage and the second for Linux?

I'm trying to boot into Debian from a Window 7 PC which I'm trying to repair after both the mouse and keyboard stopped working once I get to the login screen (different topic)... I already checked in the BIOS to have Fast Boot and Secure Boot disabled and CSM (Compatibility Support Module) enabled, as well as the boot order modified to check USB drives first. I also entered the boot menu pressing F8, where I found the two USB partitions (one labeled as UEFI and the other not) and tried both, but it simply doesn't work.

Also, is there a free Windows tool with which I can get the job done (partitioning USB stick, format one partition as Windows-accessible storage, install bootable Debian on the other)?

By the way, Windows shows both partitions as independent drives (`E:\`, `F:\`), but the second one that contains Debian is not readable. I think this is due to the incompatible file system (probably `ext4`).

Please consider that I don't have access to a Linux machine at the moment, which is in fact one of the reasons I need to create this live Linux USB stick. I only have access to a Windows 10 machine and need to use tools available on this system.

PS.: For some stupid reason, Windows won't let you create more than one partition on USB drives. There appears to be some hack to install some Hitachi disk driver in order to trick Windows into thinking that your pen drive is a disk. While I can't say for sure, I need to warn against trying this as it appears to have broken my Windows 7 machine - either the driver contains some malware or it completely messes up your USB drivers, with the result that Windows no longer recognizes keyboard and mouse (both PS/2 **and** USB)!!!

Comment: does this help ? https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2137854-imaging-desktops-in-2018?page=1#entry-7753900

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately not. I already read that post, but none of the tools I tried worked (Rufus, XBoot, YUMI, and two others). They either failed displaying both partitions or one - I think XBoot - forces me to identify the ISO from a list that hasn't Debian in it although I just dragged & dropped the Debian ISO into the tool. Also, that post doesn't explain whether or not it is technically sane to install the OS into the second partition, i.e. if BIOS will look for boot sections on all partitions or just at the very first sector of the disk and fail to boot if nothing is found there

Comment: I have a vague recollection that a boot volume had to be within *n* bytes of the start of the disk, maybe within 2GB or it couldn't boot?? I don't recall whether this was an MBR limitation which may not apply to GUID… it's all just too hazy a recollection.

Comment: That is the question!

Comment: I have had Linux at the of my hard disk for years without any issues, grub does not have that limitation, see my answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

If you have Linux available, you can open up a terminal and:

Delete any partition on the USB (please note that `#` means `root` and change the 'X' in `sdX` with the appropriate letter)

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1
```

Create new ones:

```
# fdisk /dev/sdX
> n
> p
> 1
(+1GB)
> a
> 1
(toggles boot flag)
> t
> c
(filesystem type)
> n
> p
> 2
(defaults)
> t
(specify 2nd partition)
> c
(filesystem type)
> p
(prints current configuration)
> w
(write the new table and quit)
```

Create the filesystems (this depends on your needs: might be `mkfs.ext4`, `mkfs.ntfs` etc.):

```
# mkfs.vfat /dev/sdX1
# mkfs.vfat /dev/sdX2
```

Also, is the partition table `gpt` or `mbr` (both USB and drive where your Windows is installed)?

Comment: Thanks, but this time I really need to get this done somehow from Windows 10. I usually work with Linux, but my laptop is broken and one reason I want to set up this live Linux USB stick is in order to repair it (also to pull data from another PC with Windows 7 that is also broken)

Comment: ...but I'm not sure about `gpt` or `mbr`. Is there are corresponding option in `gnome-disks` when writing an image to disk?

Comment: I see. It is possible to use `gparted` for this task if you have a spare USB.

Comment: I also don't have any spare USB sticks left at the moment... xD  Also, isn't `gparted` a Linux tool? Because I cannot boot into Linux at the moment, which is precisely why I want to create this live USB system

Comment: iirc, `gnome-disks` doesn't let you choose partition table, merely view it. You can use `gparted` as a bootable USB, that's why it would have made things easier if you had a spare one. Unfortunately, I do not know if there is an equivalent you can use by installing it on Windows. Maybe a quick Google search with "gparted alternative windows 10" could yield a usable option? Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: there is a live GPARTED iso if that helps, I have had to shrink a Windows partition without losing data, and then create a small linux partition in there.

Comment: How can I use this `gparted` ISO?

Comment: You need a USB stick with about 400MB free and [here](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php) you can find the instructions on how to install it to said USB.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use the hybrid image of Debian which already contains space for your data.

- Use RUFUS to burn the Debian Hybrid ISO to USB
- After that you should see a secondary partition on that USB to copy your files

Here are the original detailed instructions fro Linux but they give you and insisight of how is the general process.

Taken from Debian website - https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/ch04s03.html.en

```
 Debian CD and DVD images can now be written directly to a USB stick, which is a very easy way to make a bootable USB stick. Simply choose a CD or DVD image (such as the netinst, CD-1, DVD-1, or netboot) that will fit on your USB stick. See Section 4.1, “Official Debian GNU/Linux CD/DVD-ROM Sets” to get a CD or DVD image.

Alternatively, for very small USB sticks, only a few megabytes in size, you can download the mini.iso image from the netboot directory (at the location mentioned in Section 4.2.1, “Where to Find Installation Images”).

The CD or DVD image you choose should be written directly to the USB stick, overwriting its current contents. For example, when using an existing GNU/Linux system, the CD or DVD image file can be written to a USB stick as follows, after having made sure that the stick is unmounted:

    # cp debian.iso /dev/sdX
    # sync

The win32diskimager utility can be used under other operating systems to copy the image.

### Important

**The image must be written to the whole-disk device and not a partition, e.g. /dev/sdb and not /dev/sdb1. Do not use tools like unetbootin which alter the image.**

Simply writing the CD or DVD image to USB like this should work fine for most users. The other options below are more complex, mainly for people with specialised needs.

**The hybrid image on the stick does not occupy all the storage space, so it may be worth considering using the free space to hold firmware files or packages or any other files of your choice. This could be useful if you have only one stick or just want to keep everything you need on one device.**

Create a second, FAT partition on the stick, mount the partition and copy or unpack the firmware onto it. For example:

    # mount /dev/sdX2 /mnt
    # cd /mnt
    # tar zxvf /path/to/firmware.tar.gz
    # cd /
    # umount /mnt

You might have written the mini.iso to the USB stick. In this case the second partition doesn't have to be created as, very nicely, it will already be present. Unplugging and replugging the USB stick should make the two partitions visible.
```

**UPDATE:**

"Hybrid" ISO image files suitable for writing to DVD-R(W) media, and also USB keys of the appropriate size.

You can get it :

- For AMD - https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/
- For Intel - https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/i386/iso-hybrid/

Regarding if you are able to set the size of the hybrid partion, I have not found information about that, so download the ISO, follow this steps https://linuxhint.com/debian_10_bootable_usb_install/ and let me know if you need more help

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestions. This sounds like a solution, having an installation that doesn't take up the whole drive, but is bootable and leaves extra space for storage. But what is a "hybrid ISO" and is this the correct file to download ("ISO-hybrid"): https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/

Comment: ...also, how do I set the size of the partitions? Is it the "persistent partition size" option in Rufus?

Comment: I have updated my answer, also if you have found it useful the upvote is appreciated.